# spring jdbc plugin throws dataSource or jdbcTemplate not found

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

After adding the spring-jdbc plugin to my pom.xml, the application keep saying that `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required` and other errors related to data sources.

The problem in my case is that I am not interested in having a default data source. I want to run the application without having a default data source.

In this application I am selecting the data source I need and then I am using the in selected data source in my DAOs.

So how can I tell spring-jdbc to not try and set a data source for me in case I don't need one?

Later: I went deeper with my investigation and now I am getting `No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dataSource, anotherDataSource`. My understanding is that it needs only one datasource.

I also forgot to mention that I am using JNDI

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/anotherDataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Comment: When constructing a `JdbcTemplate` one is required, when using `JdbcDaoSupport` one is required. If you don't want this don't use those classes.